# How can I use substr in laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I use Laravel 5.3

My laravel eloquent is like this :

```
$query = User::where('year', '=', (string)$object->year)               
             ->where(\DB::raw('substr(code, 1, 3)'), '=', 511)
             ->get();
```

I try like that, but it does not work

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you trying to use `substr` of php or the database? Also, which database are you working with?

Comment: @linuxartisan, I use mongodb and mysql

Comment: Tried `where(\DB::raw('substr(code, 1, 3)'), '=', '511')` ?

Comment: Well, I know `substr` is a php function and is not a mysql function. So please tell whether you are trying to use the php `substr` or not. If yes, then the way you are trying it is incorrect. You can't give it to mysql to interpret.

Answer (score 5):

you forgot to put comma after '=' sign. try this .

```
   $query = User::where('year', '=', (string)$object->year)               
           ->where(\DB::raw('substr(code, 1, 3)'), '=' , 511)
           ->get();
```

Comment: i think there is a problem in $object->year that you are passing in where condition .

Answer (score 2):

Late on this thread but for anyone who is having the same issue with the aforementioned topic i found a solution by concatenating the value. For example :-

```
return User::whereRaw('SUBSTRING(column, -2,  2) = '.$value)->get();
```

Hope this helps.